# How can a CGI server based on CGIHTTPRequestHandler require that a script start its response with headers that include a `content-type`?

Tags: python, cgi

Later note:  the issues in the original posting below have been largely resolved.

Here's the background:  For an introductory comp sci course, students develop html and server-side Python 2.7 scripts using a server provided by the instructors.  That server is based on CGIHTTPRequestHandler, like the one at [pointlessprogramming](http://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/).  When the students' html and scripts seem correct, they port those files to a remote, slow Apache server.  Why support two servers?  Well, the initial development using a local server has the benefit of reducing network issues and dependency on the remote, weak machine that is running Apache.  Eventually porting to the Apache-running machine has the benefit of publishing their results for others to see.

For the local development to be most useful, the local server should closely resemble the Apache server.  Currently there is an important difference:  Apache requires that a script start its response with headers that include a `content-type`; if the script fails to provide such a header, Apache sends the client a 500 error ("Internal Server Error"), which too generic to help the students, who cannot use the server logs.  CGIHTTPRequestHandler imposes no similar requirement.  So it is common for a student to write header-free scripts that work with the local server, but get the baffling 500 error after copying files to the Apache server.  It would be helpful to have a version of the local server that checks for a `content-type` header and gives a good error if there is none.

I seek advice about creating such a server.  I am new to Python and to writing servers.  Here are the issues that occur to me, but any helpful advice would be appreciated.

1. Is a `content-type` header required by the CGI standard?  If so, other people might benefit from an answer to the main question here.  Also, if so, I despair of finding a way to disable Apache's requirement.  Maybe the relevant part of the [CGI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) is section 6.3.1 (CGI Response, Content-Type):  "If an entity body is returned, the script MUST supply a Content-Type field in the response."
2. To make a local server that checks for the `content-type` header, perhaps I should sub-class CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler, to override run_cgi() with a version that issues an error for a missing header.  I am looking at CGIHTTPServer.py `__version__ = "0.4"`, which was installed with Python 2.7.3.  But run_cgi() does a lot of processing, so it is a little unappealing to copy all its code, just to add a couple calls to a header-checking routine.  Is there a better way?
3. If the answer to (2) is something like "No, overriding run_cgi() is recommended," I anticipate writing a version that invokes the desired script, then checks the script's output for headers before that output is sent to the client.  There are apparently two places in the existing run_cgi() where the script is invoked:

   - 3a.  When run_cgi() is executed on a non-Unix system, the script is executed using Python's `subprocess` module.  As a result, the standard output from the script will be available as an in-memory string, which I can presumably check for headers before the call to `self.wfile.write`.  Does this sound right?
   - 3b.  But when run_cgi() is executed on a *nix system, the script is executed by a forked process.  I think the child's stdout will write directly to self.wfile (I'm a little hazy on this), so I see no opportunity for the code in run_cgi() to check the output.  Ugh.  Any suggestions?
4. If analyzing the script's output is recommended, is email.parser the standard way to recognize whether there is a `content-type` header?  Is another standard module recommended instead?
5. Is there a more appropriate forum for asking the main question ("How can a CGI server based on CGIHTTPRequestHandler require...")?  It seems odd to ask if there is a better forum for asking programming questions than Stack Overflow, but I guess anything is possible.

Thanks for any help.